# Scripts or commands for Moving files from a directory if it stays there for more than 30 min

Tags: shell

I need to write a script which will move files that will stay in that directory for more than 30 min.
For example there is a dir called `/var/test/` inside it there are some files coming in.
These files move to another directory for getting processed by another script ok.
So what happens is some of the files they don't get processed and stay in `/var/test/` dir which i don't want.

I am using hp-unix and i tried this command:

```
find /var/home/dacorftp/prt_output/SAP-PO/input_special -maxdepth 1 -mmin -30 -type f -exec mv "{}" /var/home/dacorftp/prt_output/SAP-PO/ErrorFilesDir \;
```

`ErrorFilesDir` is the directory where i want the moved files to get stored.

but the command doesn't work as `maxdepth` and `mmin` don't work on hp-unix.

Also can i add a utility which will mail me and tell that the file has been moved and you should start working on the  errors?

Comment: Hi :) is it in Linux OS? Maybe BASH?

Comment: i am using hp-unix

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can do

`find /path/to/search -type f -mmin +30 | xargs -I mv {} /destination/path`

But for more complex logic (like check if the files have been moved and reload the source path file list) I would recommend using Golang application.

Comment: i am using this command below to move :find  /path/ -type f -mtime -1 -exec mv "{}" /path/ \;  mmin doesn't work on hpux but mtime seem to work.